# Accessing data files after distribution using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a multiplatform project in which I required to ship few third party executable/ data files which are not part of python. In the source file I kept it under data directory and from main script calling the executable using this line

```py
trd_prt_exe = os.path.join("tools", "syslinux", "bin", "executable_name")
```

It works perfectly fine while testing/ developing from source. Problem comes when I distribute the same using `setup.py`. After installing application using setup.py, I get this error

```py
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join("tools"))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 276, in walk
    names = listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Clearly, python could not find my executables under data directory.

How can we access these executables/ data files during development and after distributing it.

**Update I**

I could have included but simply forgot. Here is my complete project strecture:-

```
[sundar@arch multibootusb-7.0.0]$ tree 
.
├── data
│   ├── multibootusb.desktop
│   └── multibootusb.png
├── LICENSE.txt
├── multibootusb
├── PKG-INFO
├── README.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── detect_iso.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── install_distro.py
│   ├── install_syslinux.py
│   ├── isodump.py
│   ├── multibootusb_ui.py
│   ├── qemu.py
│   ├── uninstall_distro.py
│   ├── update_cfg.py
│   └── var.py
├── setup.py
└── tools
    ├── checking.gif
    ├── mbr.bin
    ├── multibootusb
    │   ├── chain.c32
    │   ├── extlinux.cfg
    │   ├── grub.exe
    │   ├── memdisk
    │   ├── menu.c32
    │   ├── menu.lst
    │   ├── syslinux.cfg
    │   └── vesamenu.c32
    ├── multibootusb.png
    ├── syslinux
    │   └── bin
    │       ├── syslinux3
    │       ├── syslinux4
    │       ├── syslinux5
    │       └── syslinux6
    └── version.txt
```

Here is what I have in `setup.py`:-

```
from distutils.core import setup
import os
mbusb_version = open(os.path.join("tools", "version.txt"), 'r').read().strip()
setup(
    name='multibootusb',
    version=mbusb_version,
    packages=['scripts'],
    scripts = ['multibootusb'],
    platforms = ['Linux'],
    url='http://multibootusb.org/',
    license='General Public License (GPL)',
    author='Sundar',
    author_email='feedback.multibootusb@gmail.com',
    description='Create multi boot Live linux on a USB disk...',
    long_description = 'The multibootusb is an advanced cross-platform application for installing/uninstalling Linux operating systems on to USB flash drives.',
    data_files = [("/usr/share/applications",["data/multibootusb.desktop"]),
                  ('/usr/share/pixmaps',["data/multibootusb.png"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools',["tools/checking.gif"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools',["tools/mbr.bin"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools',["tools/version.txt"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/chain.c32"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/extlinux.cfg"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/grub.exe"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/memdisk"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/menu.c32"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/menu.lst"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/syslinux.cfg"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/multibootusb',["tools/multibootusb/vesamenu.c32"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/syslinux/bin',["tools/syslinux/bin/syslinux3"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/syslinux/bin',["tools/syslinux/bin/syslinux4"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/syslinux/bin',["tools/syslinux/bin/syslinux5"]),
                  ('multibootusb/tools/syslinux/bin',["tools/syslinux/bin/syslinux6"])]
                  #('multibootusb/tools',["tools/multibootusb.png"])]


)
```

The problem what I found is that the main executable script "multibootusb" is available in `usr/bin/multibootusb` but other data/ third party executables are under `/usr/multibootusb/` and other modules/s scripts required by main program multibootusb is under `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scripts`. Therefore, the main program is unable to locate my third party data/ executables.

How to overcome this issue? where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your setup.py file?

Comment: Updated the original post with all details.